# Docker compose con ubuntu no funciona

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Estoy haciendo un docker-compose.yml con el siguiente contenido, pero me el resultado es un exited code 1.

```
web:
  image: ubuntu
```

Al intentar con otra imagen funciona, pero menos con ubuntu o debian

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro que el contenido sea el apropiado para el compose, debes declarar una versión y `web` debería estar dentro de la sección `services`. Por lo tanto, el contenido de tu archivo debería verse más o menos así:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    image: ubuntu
```

Luego intenta haciendo el `build`:

```
$ docker-compose build
```

Comment: Recomiendo el uso de `docker-compose up -d --build` si solo va a usar un contenedor de este tipo

Answer (score 0):

Te falta agregar la **versión** al `.yaml` y el tipo de servicio. Para una imagen de `ubuntu` sería algo así:

```
version: 3
services:
  ubuntu:
    image: ubuntu:rolling
```

Comment: @BetaAthe : cuando es importante la indentación (como en este caso, o como en Python), debe ser el autor de la respuesta/pregunta quien corrija su código.